# Baking details from high poly to low poly

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, texture-baking, baking

I've lost a bit of detail during the retopology stage of my character. Is it possible to bake the detail from my high poly onto my low poly with the model I have? I've tried to bake the detail but according to the image in my UV editor, I don't think it was a successful bake.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks

High Poly:
[image]
Low Poly:
[image]

Blender File: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/097d882bbf5f8c515edc7d47055a3dc120230616175134/0fbbe2b47308cf49e200e18aecc3b5b620230616175154/ee235a

After bake:
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems to work fine, first apply the scale of your lp, give a bit of Extrusion in the Bake panel (like 0.01), select the hp, shift select the lp, bake

Comment: That said the unwrap is bad, you need to unwrap again, otherwise you'll have overlapping UVs and a bad result on some parts

Comment: Hey moonboots, I've done your recommendations and it seemed to help. I do notice there are smears over my model and the UV. (Pictures provided above) Is there a way to clean that up? Thanks

Comment: have you unwrapped again?

Comment: A simple U > Unwrap should work, it's still bad around the sex of the character but you can correct with painting

Comment: Thanks Moonboots, I'll keep at it.

Comment: also maybe try an higher Extrusion value, like 0.06

Answer (score 0):

The unwrap is bad, you need to unwrap again, otherwise you'll have overlapping UVs and a bad result on some parts. Also apply the scale of your lp, give a bit of *Extrusion* in the Bake panel (like 0.06), select the hp, shift select the lp, bake, it works. Some parts may not work where the faces are pretty close, you could paint the basic normal color on the map in the *Image Editor*.